# Rails: Form in static pages of high voltage gem

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, high-voltage

I have created few static pages with awesome [high_voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) gem.

My pages are static, except a different form in each page.

Forms are supposed to grab user details and send emails (and may be save details in db)

**Question:**

How should I proceed with this ?

I am concerned more about rails approach,

e.g.

1. How can I add validation without custom coding (both at client / server side)
2. How can take help from rails helper method ?

Suppose, I would like to save those fields in db, how should I deal with that ?

In nutshell, I want to use as maximum of rails magic without manually dealing with things.

***What I have tried ?***

Currently, I have forms in each page. Each form posts at same controller (PagesController) with `post` method.

I then differentiate them, based on hidden input on respective form.

I do not have any validations for now.

Comment: Proceed with what? What is your goal? What isn't working? What errors are you seeing? Where is you code?

Comment: Since, I do not have any controller, I just have few html pages. Where should I submit my form and how to deal with that on backend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally created a model without activerecord, following [this great article](http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/).

I created a model like below.

```
class Message

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :subject, :body

  validates :name, :email, :subject, :body, :presence => true
  validates :email, :format => { :with => %r{.+@.+\..+} }, :allow_blank => true

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this post in more detail here:
[Render partial from static page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293225/render-partial-from-static-page/20434043#20434043)

Here is the commit to a demo repository to make this work:
https://github.com/harlow/high_voltage_demo/commit/0cdbca5b0fe898d27df22787498fc7e350e81422